# How to Spawn a certain amount of enemies?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a game based off of the Asgamer tutorials. I am currently trying to make 5 enemies spawn straight away. The code to spawn the enemies is:

```
var enemy:Stinger = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
```

I know I need to loop this code 3 times somehow, but all my attempts at using loops have failed, badly. It should be noted I am just getting into Action Script so I am a complete noob at this point and I need very basic instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop. Like:

```
for (var i:Number=0; i<3, i++){
     var enemy:Stinger = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);
     enemyList.push(enemy);
     stage.addChild(enemy);
}
```

More on for loops and iterations at: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loops/

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to create five enemies, but then you say you need to loop three times.  Unless you do something unusual, looping three times will get you three enemies, and looping five times will get you five enemies.

```
var enemy:Stinger;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);
    enemyList.push(enemy);
    stage.addChild(enemy);
}
```

enemy's declaration was kept out of the loop to keep from constantly destroying and recreating the variable.  Also it sounds like you're still learning about looping, so this is basically what's happening:

```
var enemy:Stinger;
var i:int = 0;

enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip); // i = 0, i < 5
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
i++;

enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip); // i = 1, i < 5
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
i++;

enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip); // i = 2, i < 5
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
i++;

enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip); // i = 3, i < 5
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
i++;

enemy = new Stinger(stage, ourShip); // i = 4, i < 5
enemyList.push(enemy);
stage.addChild(enemy);
i++;

// i = 5; since i is no longer less than 5, stop here.
```